# How to authenticate non-windows user in .net mvc3 Windows authentication application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication

We have a MVC3 intranet application which is using Windows Authentication. Issue arises when a non-windows user (Apache/linux based system) trying access the application the user's  access is denied. Can someone suggest me possible solution, how  I can allow these non-windows  to access the application? Is it feasible in this scenario?

This is I have in web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
<membership defaultProvider="AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider"
         type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, 
             System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
             PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
         connectionStringName="ADService"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
```